# App Suspended - After using CORDOVA App Update plugin - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

**Issue with your app
Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Malicious Behavior policy. We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Cordova plugin App-update SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.**

Even I tried removing this plugin and tried so it got build but was not opening
Error was coming saying: [ERROR] Error initialization Version Plugin: Class not found

[image: Error]

Comment: ditto...how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problems in previous week. I think Google has tighten the policy due to the malicious behaviour plugin. You just need to remove and add android platform after remove the app-update plugin.

Using:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

But then, after added new android platform, try to add line:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` (inside platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

This (if am not mistaken, can correct me if wrong) is to make sure android 9 and above can work as well like before. In my case, my apps cannot access and pass value into the outside webpage if this line was not inserted.